# Rudin's Real and Complex analysis - Exercise 5 Chapter 1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Point (a) of Exercise 5 Chapter 1 in Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" requires to prove the following:

> If $f,g:X \to [-\infty, +\infty]$ are measurable then $\{x:f(x)<g(x)\}$ and $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ are measurable.

Now the natural approach (and the one that you can find pretty much everywhere the exercise has been discussed) is to notice that $f-g:X \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ is measurable and then to  write both sets as preimages of Borel subsets of $[-\infty, +\infty]$. However, Rudin has never proved that the sum of extended-real measurable functions is measurable (he has only proved it for **non-negative** extended-real functions). Now, I have found a proof of this fact by elementary means (see for instance here: [https://www.cmi.ac.in/~prateek/measure_theory/2010-09-24.pdf](https://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Eprateek/measure_theory/2010-09-24.pdf)), however that raises the question of why hasn't Rudin followed this more general road and instead only dealt, in a more obscure way, with a particular case in section 1.22. Is there something I am missing about his approach that makes it favourable?

Comment: The general case might follow from the nonnegative case, explaining Rudin's omission. Or Rudin just made a genuine oversight by not demonstrating the general result.

Comment: @FShrike You are correct about the fact that the general case follows from the nonnegative case, but just for addition. Indeed multiplication does not follow as trivially.